# Determine sphere radius and center in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: geometry

$$\begin{align*}
x &= a \sin \theta \cos \varphi\\ 
y &= a \sin \theta \sin \varphi\\
z &= a \cos \theta
\end{align*}$$

Given this is an equation of a sphere, how would I find its center and radius?

Answer (score 2):

It is centered at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ and its radius $= a$

You can do this by inspection of the conversion between Cartesian and Spherical Coordinates:

$$\begin{align*}
x &= r \cos\phi \sin\theta\\
y &= r \sin\phi \sin\theta\\
z &= r\cos\theta
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Please use `\cos` and `\sin`.

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed? Why is the radisu = a?

Comment: Compare the problem you wrote with what I wrote symbol for symbol. If you replace r with a in mine you get yours. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an intuitive picture of what is going on with these equations, you might like to consider the maximum and minimum values of the $x, y, z$ coordinates.

Since the trig functions vary between $+1$, and $-1$, it is easy to see that the maximum and minimum values of $x, y, z$ are $a$ and $-a$, so the centre is halfway between the maximum and minimum i.e. at $(0,0,0)$ and then the radius is clear.